# Unable to Find Edit Links option in global nevigaion in SharePoint On premise site

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, edit, global-navigation

in my SharePoint On premise environment i have Publishing Site .
i am trying to **Edit Links** in Global navigation .
but i am unable to see **Edit Links** option on SharePoint on premise publishing site.

[image]

Please suggest something so i can see that Edit Links opetion in SharePoint on premise site

Comment: Do you have a lots of links in the global navigation on the site? Custom masterpage? Using managed metadata navigation? You can always edit the global navigation by adding "/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx" to your site collection URL.

Comment: yes,i have lots of links in global navigation? but i don't want to edit Global navigation through "/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx"

Comment: actually i am trying to drag and drop the global navigation link   Heading-->Heading-->Link

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct permissions on the specific site? And that it does not use managed metadata navigation? Is it a root site or subsite?

Comment: It is a simple navigation using Structural navigation settings(subsites). I am trying to show 3rd level menu in global navigation. I am following this link https://newsignature.com/articles/no-code-global-navigation-flyout-dropdown-sharepoint-2013-online . I know this is for Online but I want to do the same in the on-prem.                                                                      
I am a site collection admin.

Comment: If it is a subsite, check the navigation settings on the site. If the subsite is inheriting navigation from Parent site, you have disable it. http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/09/edit-links-missing-in-sharepoint-2013-navigation.html

Comment: No it is not a subside . its a root site .